# Como unir consultas MYSQL

Tags: mysql

**Hola, Tengo estas 2 consultas las cuales al momento utilizo por separado con PHP, pero ahora necesito unir esta consulta en una sola ya que comenzare a graficar y quiero hacer procedimientos para que tenga los datos en tiempo real, lo intente con un UNION ALL pero me da el error:**

*El comando SELECT usado tiene diferente número de columnas*

Soy nuevo en Mysql y se me esta complicando.

En la siguiente imagen les muestro mis tablas y la relaciones que tiene cada una.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SELECT pedidos.*
        , reporte.*
        , usuarios.*
        , pedidos_reportes.*,
        pedidos_reportes.id 
     FROM pedidos  
       LEFT JOIN pedidos_reportes
         ON pedidos.ID = pedidos_reportes.id_pedido
       INNER JOIN ( SELECT id_pedido
                         , MAX(fecha_modificacion) as fecha_modificacion
                      FROM pedidos_reportes
                      WHERE fecha_modificacion BETWEEN '2021-06-02 16:05:11' AND now()
                      GROUP BY id_pedido
                  ) pedidos_reportes_max
         ON     pedidos_reportes.id_pedido = pedidos_reportes_max.id_pedido
           AND  pedidos_reportes.fecha_modificacion = pedidos_reportes_max.fecha_modificacion
       LEFT JOIN reporte  
         ON pedidos_reportes.id_reporte = reporte.id
       LEFT JOIN usuarios 
         ON pedidos_reportes.id_usuario = usuarios.id
         WHERE pedidos.CANTIDAD_PENDIENTE >0
```

---

```
SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT 
    pedidos.ID
      FROM pedidos
      LEFT JOIN pedidos_reportes 
      ON pedidos.ID = pedidos_reportes.id_pedido
      INNER JOIN ( SELECT id_pedido
                  , MAX(fecha_modificacion) as fecha_modificacion
                  FROM pedidos_reportes
                  GROUP BY id_pedido
              ) pedidos_reportes_max
          ON     pedidos_reportes.id_pedido = pedidos_reportes_max.id_pedido
          AND  pedidos_reportes.fecha_modificacion = pedidos_reportes_max.fecha_modificacion
      LEFT JOIN reporte  
      ON pedidos_reportes.id_reporte = reporte.id
      LEFT JOIN usuarios 
      ON pedidos_reportes.id_usuario = usuarios.id
    WHERE pedidos.CANTIDAD_PENDIENTE >0
    GROUP BY pedidos.id
    order by pedidos_reportes.fecha_modificacion desc)
    AND pedidos.CANTIDAD_PENDIENTE >0
```

En mi php llamo las dos consultas de la siguiente forma:

```
<tbody>
       <?php 
       require_once 'reprogramados_recientes.php';
       require_once 'bd-admin.php'
       ?>
</tbody>
```

Y el resultado me imprime todos los datos de pedidos y a su derecha se le agregan los datos que se relacionan de las tablas de pedidos_reportes, usuarios y reporte.

Ejemplo:

ID | BDD | Empresa | Serie | Folio | Cliente || ID_reporte | fecha || ID_usuario | Usuario |  Clave

Comment: Explica que queres decir por unir (no es lo mismo poner una atras de la otra, que una al costado de la otra).. Pone un ejemplo claro de datos de entrada, y como queres que quede la salida.. asi como esta, es imposible decirte que tenes que hacer

Comment: Las dos consultas deben coincidir en la parte del select con el mismo número de campos y el mismo tipo para que el unión sea correcto. En tu caso son distintas (la primera tiene todos los campos de varias tablas, y la segunda solo tiene los de una tabla)